# Will there be generic attributes in C# 4?

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

So - if [there isn't particular reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-forbid-generic-attribute-types) why there isn't generic attributes,
I'm wondering - maybe they will be implemented?

Those would be great for ASP.NET MVC action filters.

Comment: Luckily there are alternative ways to attach filters nowadays...

Comment: What are these alternative ways you speak of?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I haven't seen any evidence of this in the [4.0 spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/6/7E6A548C-9C20-4C80-B3B8-860FAF20887A/CSharp%204.0%20Specification.doc)... so I believe the answer is "no".

Comment: It's hard to accept answer which i didn't want to hear. -_-

Comment: Correct. That feature continues to be very low on the priority list.

Comment: Always good to get a definitive answer; thanks Eric.

Answer (score 8):

C# 4 specification does not mention generics in attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Shame, stumbled across a case where I wanted to use this in a ValidationAttribute.

Something that can check whether a given collection is empty. In general, this could be with a generic or non generic parameter.

```
public override Boolean IsValid(Object value)
    {
        var v = value as ICollection<T>;

        return v.Count > 0;
    }
```

Would be useful if I could do this.

Comment: I'd also like to combine generics and the ValidationAttribute. It would be nice if the ValidationAttribute implemented an IValidatable and inherited from Attribute.