# Convert string to Func<T,Object>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have the following method

```
     public List<ServicesLogModel> Paging(Func<ServicesLogModel, bool> condition, string columnOrder, bool? orderDescending, int? pageIndex, int? pageSize, out int total)
    {
         return _mongoRepository.Paging(condition, order => order.Message, orderDescending.Value, pageIndex.Value, pageSize.Value, out total);
    }
```

The `columnOrder` parameter is a string as lambda expression (ex: `order => order.Message`) that I must cast to `Func<T, object>`

I'm trying with `Expression.Parameter`

```
 var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ServicesLogModel), "order");

        var propName = Expression.Property(parm, columnOrder);

        Expression predicateBody = Expression.Assign(parm, propName);


        var test=Expression.Lambda<Func<ServicesLogModel, object>>(predicateBody, parm);
```

it doesn't work
Error :You can not use an expression of type 'System.String' for an assignment to type 'ServicesLogModel'

Edit :Method Signature

```
public List<T> Paging(Func<T, bool> condition, Func<T, object> order, bool orderDescending, int pageIndex, int pageSize,out int total)
```

Call method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Admin/GetReaderConnectorLog/{Apikey}/{SecretKey}/{index}/{pagesize}/{orderAsc}/{columnOrder}")]
    public IActionResult GetReaderConnectorLog(string Apikey, string SecretKey, int? index, int? pagesize, bool? orderAsc, string columnOrder)
    {
        try
        {
            _userService.BeginTransaction();
            //  _webApiHelper.ValidateApiKey(Apikey, SecretKey, Context, _userService, true);
            int total;
            //TEST
            var listModel = _connectorLogService.Paging(_ => true, $"order => order.{columnOrder}", orderAsc, index, pagesize, out total);
            _userService.Commit();
            return _webApiHelper.OkResponse($"{_appSettings.Options.UserTag}[Send List User]", Context, new PaginationModel<ServicesLogModel> { ListData = listModel, Total = total, Apikey = Apikey, SecretKey = SecretKey });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _userService.Rollback();
            return _webApiHelper.ResolveException(Context, e);
        }
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Define "it isn't work"

Comment: Just for the record, you can use Predicate<ServicesLogModel> instead of Func<ServicesLogModel, bool> when your return type is boolean.

Comment: @msmolcic `Predicate` predates `Func`, it is perfectly acceptable to use the more general purpose `Func`. See for example LINQ's [Where clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) `public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
 this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
 Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)`. All of LINQ uses `Func<T, bool>` and does not anywhere use `Predicate<T>`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I just said he can use it, did not say it's a must or whatever.

Comment: @msmolcic Actually he must use Func, if `Paging(` takes in a `Func<ServicesLogModel, bool>` as the first parameter and you pass in a `Predicate<ServicesLogModel>` you will get a compiler error *"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Predicate<ServicesLogModel>' to 'System.Func<ServicesLogModel, bool>`"* because delegates are not implicitly convertable even if they have the same signature.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Actually he can change paging and use Predicate

Comment: so the string `columnOrder` parameter column holds the name of the column that you want to use to order the data? e.g. "Message"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string to C# lambda Func](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707854/parse-string-to-c-sharp-lambda-func)

Comment: yes                                                                                                         `code`public sealed class ServicesLogModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Exception { get; set; }
    }`code`

Answer (score 3):

Well , the final solution was this

```
public Func<T, object> GetLambda<T>(string property)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        Expression parent = Expression.Property(param, property);

        if (!parent.Type.IsValueType)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(parent, param).Compile();
        }
        var convert = Expression.Convert(parent, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(convert, param).Compile();
    }
```

Comment: Your solution should be better in terms of performance since it uses expressions to create a function which is faster than using reflection. By the way, I am curious to know if the solution I provided works or not.

Comment: Hi Yacoub Massad , finally your solution doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Since your method requires `Func<T,object>` and not `Expression<Func<T,object>>`, a simple solution is to use reflection:

```
public Func<T, object> GetPropertyFunc<T>(string property_name)
{
    return t => typeof (T).GetProperty(property_name).GetMethod.Invoke(t, new object[] {});
}
```

This method takes the name of the property, and it returns the required function.

And here is how you can test it:

```
ServicesLogModel model = new ServicesLogModel()
{
    Message = "my message"
};

Func<ServicesLogModel, object> func = GetPropertyFunc < ServicesLogModel>("Message"); //I am assuming the property name is "Message", but you can pass any string here

var message = func(model) as string;
```

Comment: it doesn't work , because not order the list by "message" property ...this way work (_mongoRepository.Paging(condition, p=> p.Message, orderDescending.Value, pageIndex.Value, pageSize.Value, out total) ) , but this way not ( return _mongoRepository.Paging(condition, func, orderDescending.Value, pageIndex.Value, pageSize.Value, out total) )

Comment: Are you sure that your Paging method accepts a `Func<T, object> order` and not `Expression<Func<T, object> order>`?

Comment: yes ..... (public List<T> Paging(Func<T, bool> condition, Func<T, object> order, bool orderDescending, int pageIndex, int pageSize,out int total)

Comment: So, if this is not working, what exactly is not working? is it giving you wrong results? or is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Does the columnOrder variable equal to `"Message"` or `"order => order.Message"`?

Comment: i need that works this way "order => order.Message" not by the content of "message" variable..

Comment: Can you please provide in the question an example of how you want to invoke the first Paging method?

Comment: Since you are specifying the value of the argument, why not simply change it to `"Message"` instead of `"order => order.Message"`? are you planning to support more complex selectors like `"order => order.Customer.Name"`?

Comment: in the future , i will sort by foreach property of ServicesLogModel model  ( order => order.Date, order => order.Exception ) etc..

Comment: Why do you want columnOrder to be a string, why not make it `Func<T,object>` or `Expression<Func<T,object>>`? I am starting to get confused. Can you please explain your intention in the question?

Comment: because I receive this parameter from a web application, i'm building a rest api, so this parameter is dynamic , for that, i must recieve as string

Comment: And do you receive a string like `"order => order.Message"`? Can we assume that it will always be in the format `"order => order.XXXXXX"`? if so, you can simply parse this string to get the `"XXXXXX"` piece (which is the property name) and then use the function I provided to obtain a Func<T,object>. Or are you expecting complex expressions like `"order => order.ZZZZZZ.XXXXXX"`?

Comment: no.. i receive the just the object property ("Message") and i concat the rest of the string ( $"order => order.{columnOrder}")

Comment: how do it that??? ( you can simply parse this string to get the "XXXXXX" piece (which is the property name) and then use the function I provided to obtain a Func<T,object>)

Comment: That my function should be a perfect fit. Just pass "Message" (the property name) to my function and it should work

Comment: Since you receive the property name, you don't have to parse any thing, just pass the property name as is to the function I provided (`GetPropertyFunc`)

Comment: works !!!! but this way                                                    ServicesLogModel model = new ServicesLogModel();
          
            Func<ServicesLogModel, object> func = GetPropertyFunc(model, "Message");





            return _mongoRepository.Paging(condition, order => order.Exception, orderDescending.Value, pageIndex.Value, pageSize.Value, out total);  Thank you very much

Comment: The GetPropertyFunc receives one parameter, not two. When I answered the question they were two (I did a mistake), but immediately I changed it to one. I cannot see how you are using the func variable. Please review your last comment.

Comment: change this (ServicesLogModel model = new ServicesLogModel()
{
    Message = "my message"
}; )  for this  (  ( ServicesLogModel model = new ServicesLogModel();)

Comment: Why would this change any behavior? Are you using the GetPropertyFunc method that receives one or two arguments?

Comment: two arguments, the same method that you programming

Comment: I updated my answer immediately after writing it. It seems you have the old answer. Sorry for that. Please refresh your browser. Currently, the method has only one argument. `public Func<T, object> GetPropertyFunc<T>(string property_name)`