# Use C# Expression Evaluator for filtering a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, csharpeval

We have a `List<SomeType>` and want to be able to run different actions on it like selecting elements meeting some criteria. We want these tests to be provided by the user in text, so are looking at [C# Expression Evaluator](https://csharpeval.codeplex.com/).

It can certainly be used for this purpose but I'm struggling to tell if a `csharpeval` delegate can be used as a lambda when using LINQ. We want our stored expressions to be applied to each object.

e.g. Just `"o.FirstName == "Tom"` and *not* store the whole list expression like `list.Where(o => o.FirstName == 'Tom')`.

Methods to compile an expression once and run against different input data are provided through `ScopeCompile` but I'm not sure if these are compatible with lambda methods. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you looked into using Roslyn directly for this? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#expr

Comment: @user9993 no, although their example "Create & build a C# script and execute it multiple times" looks quite similar. Obviously I can write an explicit loop, lambdas are mainly for style :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1707854/1271037, http://stackoverflow.com/q/821365/1271037

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I this is what you want:

```
var expression = new CompiledExpression<bool>("MyProperty > 10");
var func = expression.ScopeCompile<MyClass>();
```

Example usage:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => new MyClass { MyProperty = x });

var expression = new CompiledExpression<bool>("MyProperty > 10");
var func = expression.ScopeCompile<MyClass>();

var filtered = list.Where(p => func(p));

Console.WriteLine(filtered.Count()); //40
```

You can create a helper function to create the lambda functions:

```
Func<T, bool> GetLambda<T>(string inputExp)
{
    var expression = new CompiledExpression<bool>(inputExp);
    return expression.ScopeCompile<T>();
}
```

Usage:

```
var func = GetLambda<People>("Id < 5");
Peoples.Where(p => func(p)).Dump();
```