# what is name of the List<T> design pattern called? how to implement it

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns, model-view-controller

As we know that the List for C# is possible to put the function behind but do the function to filter the list.

For example,
Assume that the many count inside the students List.

```
var students=new List<student>();
```

Then to get the list of student we can add some function behind like

```
students.find(id).sortbydesending(k=>k.x).skip(10).take(5).toList();
```

the sequence of putting the skip() and take() will effect the result.

I was doing the coding on an method to retrieve the list of student accordingly.

**First**,
I want to do something similar with the list function.
For example i need order the list Of Student According student name.

instead of doing

```
students.sortbydescending(k=>k.name).toList();
```

I want code is like

```
students.sortbyNamedesc().toList();
```

and it will return the same result as above.

**Second** is the design pattern name and (If possible) implementation guide

This is because I plan to do something like this.

```
getStudent().searchName(searchQuery).sortby(id);
```

Then i can get student name similar with search query and sort it by the student id instead of

```
getstudent(searchQuery,id,skip,take);

public IList<Student> getStudent(searchQuery,id,skip,take){
   var students=new List<student>();
   if(searchquery!="")
        students.where(x=>x.x==searchquery);

   if(skip!=null&&skip!=0)
        students.skip(skip);

   if(take!=null&&take!=0)
     students.take(take);

    return students;

  }
```

Comment: For the first: this is extension methods are for. For second: you looking something like "convert" string to `Func<>`, there are bunch of question of this topic on stackoverflow. (for example: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707854/parse-string-to-c-sharp-lambda-func](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707854/parse-string-to-c-sharp-lambda-func))

Comment: what do you mean "are for"?

Comment: I mean you can create extension method for type `List<Student>` with name `SortByNameDesc`.

Comment: The idea to `Keep().Chaining().Methods()` is called a _fluent interface_ (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html), and "adding" methods to types you don't own is done using _extension methods_ as others have already mentioned.

Comment: Defenitively worth reading in this context: [Jon Skeet's Edulinq](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq)

Answer (score 3):

These are called *extension methods*. You define them as static methods in static classes, with a `this` before the first parameter. For example:

```
public static class StudentExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Student> OrderByNameDescending(this IEnumerable<Student> source)
    {
        return source.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
studentList.OrderByNameDescending()
```

(The static class must be accessible at the point of usage and you must be in its namespace, or include it with a `using` statement.)

Comment: What about the second part? :)

Comment: @Fabio I don't quite understand the second part. If the OP needs the answer to cover something more specifically, I can wait until they clarify.