# Workaround for C# generic attribute limitation

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-sharp-forbid-generic-attribute-types), C# doesn't support generic attribute declaration.
So, I'm not allowed to do something like:

```
[Audit<User> (UserAction.Update)]
public ActionResult SomeMethod(int id){ ...
```

that would fit like a charm in my attribute impl class, cause I need to call a method from a generic repository:

```
User fuuObj = (User) repository.LoadById<T>(_id);
```

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method) solution without success. I can pass something like `typeOf(User)`, but how can I call `LoadById` just with type or magic string?

*Both, T and User, extend a base class called Entity.

Comment: could you write different attributes for each type?

Comment: Do you need a specific class or is Entity enough to work with?

Comment: @Daniel, yes... but I actually prefer center all auditory process and avoid maximum as possible future code in this context.

Comment: I really hope by .NET5 they address these huge glaring pain points for dealing with generics, it's absolutely silly i can't do `var t = typeof(Cat); new Repository<t>().DoMagic();`

Comment: Finally on the roadmap for C# 10.0 ... [github discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/124)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use reflection to load by id:

```
public class AuditAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AuditAttribute(Type t)
    {
        this.Type = t;
    }

    public  Type Type { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //type is not Entity
        if (!typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(Type))
            throw new Exception();

        int _id;

        IRepository myRepository = new Repository();
        MethodInfo loadByIdMethod =  myRepository.GetType().GetMethod("LoadById");
        MethodInfo methodWithTypeArgument = loadByIdMethod.MakeGenericMethod(this.Type);
        Entity myEntity = (Entity)methodWithTypeArgument.Invoke(myRepository, new object[] { _id });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have at least these three possibilities:

1. You could use reflection to call `LoadById`
2. You could create an expression tree that calls `LoadById`
3. You could provide a `LoadById` method in your repository that is not generic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to invoke the LoadById method. The following msdn article should point you in the right direction:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 11 there is no need for workarounds because [generic attributes are  supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#generic-attributes):

```cs
public class AuditAttribute<T> : Attribute where T : Entity
{
   // ... 
}
```