# How can I have an [Attribute] that accepts a type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

I created an `EvaluateAttribute`, and I want it to accept various `IEvaluator`s specified like this:

```
[Evaluate(CatEvaluator, DogEvaluator)]
public void someMethod()
{
}
```

Since `CatEvaluator` and `DogEvaluator` are types, I set up my attribute class like this:

```
   public class EvaluateAttribute<T> : Attribute where T:IAccessEvaluator
```

and constructor:

```
public EvaluateAttribute(params T [] accessEvaluators)
{
    _accessEvaluators = accessEvaluators;
}
```

C# doesn't like generics and attributes though, it would seem. Is there a solution to this?

I want my attribute to instantiate each type with `CreateInstance` and run an evaluate method specific in `IAccessEvaluator`.

Comment: please check this out: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-sharp-forbid-generic-attribute-types

Greetings

Comment: I saw that before posting, it doesn't contain a solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to use generics if you just want to pass classes implementing `IAccessEvaluator`. Just change the signature to

```
public EvaluateAttribute(params IAccessEvaluator [] accessEvaluators)
{
    _accessEvaluators = accessEvaluators;
}
```

Reread your question. You're using types like objects, so my first impression was to write the above answer. If you need to annotate types, you should have a look at the comment on your question (by MUG4N).

```
public EvaluateAttribute(params Type [] accessEvaluators)
{
    _accessEvaluators = accessEvaluators;
}

[Evaluate(typeof(CatEvaluator), typeof(DogEvaluator)]
public SomeClass{ }
```

and change `_accessEvaluators` to  `Type[]`

Comment: but `[Attribute(CatEvaluator)]` then says `CatEvaluator` is a type used as an object or similar

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to stop the attribute accepting types:

```
public class EvaluateAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly Type[] _accessEvaluators;

    public EvaluateAttribute(params Type[] accessEvaluators)
    {
        _accessEvaluators = accessEvaluators;
    }
}
```

which you can then use like this:

```
[Evaluate(typeof(CatEvaluator), typeof(DogEvaluator)]
public void someMethod()
{

}
```

Unfortunately, you lose the type safety - but you could always add some run-time checking to the attribute's constructor. Something along the lines of:

```
public EvaluateAttribute(params Type[] accessEvaluators)
{
    foreach (var type in accessEvaluators)
    {
        if (!typeof(IAccessEvaluator).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Suppied type must be of type IAccessEvaluator");
        }
    }
    _accessEvaluators = accessEvaluators;
}
```