# KnownType attribute cannot use type parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have this Web Api controller action:

```
public Plant<TissueProductionLine> GetPlant(string plant, string range)
{
    return _repo.GetPlant(plant, range);
}
```

Firing this up I get this:

> Type 'IGMProdLineDashboard.Models.TissueProductionLineGroup' with data contract name 'IGMProdLineDashboard.Models' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Ok, no problem, I'll just decorate my `Plant` object with the `[KnownType]` attribute and specify the non-primitive property:

```
[KnownType(typeof(ProductionLineGroups<T>))]
public class Plant<T>: IPlant<T> where T : IProductionLine
{
    public Plant ()
    {
        ProductionLineGroups = new ProductionLineGroups<T>();
    }
    public ProductionLineGroups<T> ProductionLineGroups { get; set; }
```

Now I get a compile-time error:

> 'IGMProdLineDashboard.Models.ProductionLineGroups': an attribute argument cannot use type parameters

Re-reading the first message, it wants to know about the derived type: `TissueProductionLineGroup`

If I decorate my `Plant` object with this, everything works:

```
[KnownType(typeof(TissueProductionLineGroup))]
```

Obviously the implication here is my `Plant` now needs to know about all different kinds of production lines, which means I'll need to update the `Plant` whenever a new group is added.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the error message isn't misleading you at all. Attributes cannot use generic type parameters. As far as I know, there is no way around the issue.

Jon Skeet formerly posted an answer on the matter and said that the C# team chose to add this restraint in order to keep the compiler code simpler, although there is no reason why the CLI cant represent generic attributes.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/294259/2394286

Comment: Yes, I saw that it got a little heated as well. Unfortunately this scenario is coupling my code which I had worked so hard to keep decoupled...