# How to use LINQ to query a [key] property using generic types?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And now I want to create a generic `Get()` method that might query `Customer` or any one of several other classes that also have a `[key]` field defined.

```
public T Get<T>(int id)
{            
    string json = DoSomething(); // <-- making it easy for this post
    List<T> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);            
    return items.FirstOrDefault(i => i. ????? = id);
}
```

I'm not sure how to use Linq to generically specify the `[key]` field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
public interface IBase
{
    int Id { get; }
}
public class Customer : IBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get ; set ; }
}
public T Get<T>(int id) where T : IBase
{
    string json = DoSomething(); // <-- making it easy for this post
    List<T> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
    return items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
}
```

Just implement the interface `IBase` in all other classes.

Comment: You are welcome. If it works please mark it right. :)

Comment: I always do!  (just one edit you need to make:  `(i => i.Id == id)`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston - did that

Comment: This answer do not meet the criteria from the original post. It says "that also have a [key] field defined", and this post only adds a constraint for a particular interface. I suggest OP edits his question to reflect what he needed to know...

Comment: @Areks, if you'd like to post an answer that meets my OP, I'd be more than happy to consider it.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I added an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth I think using contracts is a better way to solve this. But in case you or someone else actually need to check for the attribute here's the answer:

```
public static T Get<T>(int id)
{
    string json = DoSomething(); // <-- making it easy for this post
    List<T> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

    return items.FirstOrDefault(
        item => (int)item.GetType()
                         .GetProperties()
                         .FirstOrDefault(
                            p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(KeyAttribute))
                         ).GetValue(item) == id
    );
}
```

As far a this part of your question:

> I'm not sure how to use Linq to generically specify the [key] field.

The attribute is `KeyAttribute` you can know that by navigating to the definition (pressing F12 if you're using VS or checking the docs in case your editor doesn't support this feature.

Things to consider:

- this is using Reflection reasonably heavily, so it will never have the best performance. That being said you can cache the result from `GetProperties()` somewhere for faster lookups.
- It's hardcoding the cast to `int` but it appears that's what you're after.
- If the collection is null it'll throw an exception.

Comment: So you would be reflecting on every query? When just using Naming convention you can achieve compile time goodness that the `Id` property will be generally the Key attribute. Anyways its clear the question wanted a Compile time solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521670/type-constraints-in-attributes - And btw there is `NO CAST` anywhere

Comment: Yes. It would of course use reflection every time you call the method. The question asked for the presence of an attribute, which cannot be done at compile time at the moment. And there is a cast, in the return statement.

Comment: `There is no cast`. The parameter itself in the `Get` method is an `int`. Look carefully.

Comment: Then how do you call this? (int)item.GetType()..…? Look carefully at the (int) part.

Comment: I meant there is no cast needed. `class Class1 : IBase
    {
        public int Id { get; }

        void meth()
        {
            Get<Class1>(1);
        }`

Comment: So now we went from there is no cast to not needed. Ok. Have it your way sir. I added this example because OP asked for it and it could help others, not to have a discussion about pointless remarks.

Comment: I realized it later what you meant in your answer, sorry about that.