# Custom Attributes created inside generic Class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, custom-attributes

```
public sealed class test<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : new()
{
     public sealed class Ignore : Attribute { }
}    

public class test_2
{
     [ ???? ]
     string helllo;
}
```

Is there a way to access the Attribute from outside the `test<T>` class?
I can't seem to find one.

Comment: I believe your class needs to be called IgnoreAttribute to work properly.

Comment: `[test<sometype>.Ignore]`. You must specify a type for `T`. This is because the type parameter `T` is available to nested types, even though your attributes doesn't use it.

Comment: This become very awkward to use - why have a non-generic attribute inside a generic class? Putting Attributes inside classes isn't really good practice anyway

Comment: But I cannot specify a type for T, intellisense isnt proposing some, nor does the compliler accept these
@vcsjones

Comment: Any class nested inside a generic class actually represents a different class for each different generic parameter.  So `test<sometype>.Ignore` is a different type than `test<othertype>.Ignore`.  However, as bbeda answered below, C# does not support generic attributes so you cannot embed an attribute class inside a generic one and use it as an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not support Generic Attributes. 
I know your attribute is not generic but I suppose you want it inside that generic class to use T in attribute level, which makes the Attribute generic (You'll get different Ignore type for each T)

Unfortunately you can't achieve this in C#. [Why does C# forbid generic attribute types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-sharp-forbid-generic-attribute-types?rq=1)

Updated from comments:
You can have the Ignore attribute in the scope of the namespace. The you can do reflection on `test<T>` and look for properties with Ignore attribute.

```
public sealed class Ignore : Attribute { }

public sealed class test<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : new()
{
    [Ignore]
    public test_2 SomeProperty { get; set; }
}


public class test_2
{
    [Ignore]
    public string TestData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `public sealed class test<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : new()
{
     public sealed class Ignore : Attribute { }
}    

public class test_2
{
     [test<T>.Ignore]
     string helllo;
}`

Actually not, the T is totally uninteresting for the attribute, they won't even ever be near each other in code :D

The Attribute is just to identify vars to be ignored by the reflection of `test<T>`

Comment: Yes, but you could do that if you wanted to. C# does not support that to avoid such complexities.  If they are not related why do you want to put the attribute inside that class anyway?

Comment: the attribute is related to `test<T>`, that's why I want it in there, but it's needed by other classes, so that the user can specify variables to be ignored by `test<T>`

Comment: I what sense is it related to test<t>? Conceptually, the Ignore attribute has no relation to your class. It may only if it'd do not do some fancy things using the class (which isn't the case now). They should not be related, as their purpose is totally different. From a design point of you, Ignore should not be related in any way with your class.

Comment: But ignore is needed by the `test<T>` class, because the user needs it to define vars to be ignored, if it is not in the `test<T>` class, how would a user use it then?

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it's needed vice versa, the [ignore] is to be on test_2 TestData.
And how would I make sure, that the user, who uses my `test<T>` class has this attribute, or even know of it?

Comment: What stops you adding the Ignore attribute to the test2.TestData property? You can add Ignore attribute to any property as long as the assembly and the namespace are referenced.How does a user know...? Well...how does a user know to put [Serializable] attribute on serializable classes? She gets a runtime exception! and reads the documentation:)