# call generic type T as an attribute in c#. i:e [typeof(List<T>)]

Tags: c#, generics

All remove, add and contains methods are in this class

```
public class ListClass<T>{}
```

My attribute class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ListMyDefault 
{
    public ListMyDefault(string name, Type objectType)
        : base(typeof(ListClass<>).MakeGenericType(objectType)) 
    {
            DefaultName = name;
            ObjectType = objectType;
    }
}
```

How can i use the above attribute with generic T in the property?
typeof(T) will be List of SomeClass.

```
public myclass<T>
{ 
    [ListMyDefault("sample",typeof(T)] 
    public static List<T> Details{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: typeof(T) instead of type(T)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not possible. [An attribute must be "complete" at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/294242/87698), but the concrete type of `T` is unknown at compile time.

Comment: @Krish why you will not use like this  - http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/Generic-Attributes-in-CSharp

Answer (score 3):

An attribute that references a generic type parameter will cause a compile-time error:

```
[CustomAttribute(info = typeof(GenericClass3<int, T, string>))]  //Error
class ClassD<T> { }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173129.aspx