# Build failed due to error - 'Value_Type._editor is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#

Can someone help me understand why I get this error in my code and how I can fix it?

```
'Value_Type._editor is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
```

Please see my codes below:

```
    void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        Value_Type valueType = new Value_Type(typeof(TestEditorClass));
    }
```

My `Value_Type` class:

```
    public class Value_Type
    {
        object _editor;
        string _content;

        public Value_Type(object editor)
        {
            this._editor = editor;
            this._displayName = displayName;
        }

        public string Content
        {
            get { return _content; }
            set { _content = value; }
        }

        [Editor(typeof(_editor), typeof(UITypeEditor))] // the error appears here when I pass _editor as a parameter to the attribute.
        public IRecord Key { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: it now says - 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property'

Answer (score 2):

`typeof(_editor)` isn't valid. As the error message tells you, the argument for [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/58918ffs.aspx) must be a type, e.g. `typeof(TestEditorClass)`, *not* an instance of a type.

In this case, it looks like your `_editor` *is* a type, i.e `(Type)_editor` would be more appropriate than `_editor.GetType()`.

However, neither of these on their own will resolve the issue as attribute arguments must be constants.

Comment: is there a way wherein I can pass the editor class as an argument?

Comment: @yonan2236 I'm not that familiar with this particular attribute, so I'm not sure whether there's another way of approaching this. You can't even use generics in attribute arguments [per this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-sharp-forbid-generic-attribute-types).

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your snippet

1. [`typeof()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) requires a type and you are passing a variable that's why compiler is raising an error. To get type of object you can use `object.GetType()` instead. As you are storing a Type inside `_editor` so, simply cast to type `(Type)_editor`.
2. `_editor` is a instance variable, you can't access that there. An object reference is required to access non-static member `_editor`.

Comment: by the way, what is 'TEditor' in 'public class Value_Type<TEditor>'?

Comment: TEditor is a placeholder for any type. Read here more about generics https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Should I write 'TEditor' as is? The compiler could not recognize it... Do I need to include any reference?

Comment: Just write TEditor as it. Start from C# 2.0 compiler will be able to understand that.

Comment: I'm getting this error now... 'TEditor': an attribute argument cannot use type parameters

Comment: Sorry! C# doesn't allow that. But IL supports this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/294259/2509344. Anyway I don't have access machine right now. Sorry for misguide. I've reverted changes to my answer