# Workaround for using type parameter in attribute for using ProducesResponseType with a generic type argument?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a generic ASP.NET Core WebApi controller like:

```
public abstract class EntityController<TEntity> 
{
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        var entity = ... //load from database by id
        if (entity != null) 
            return new JsonResult(value, this.SerializerSettings()) {StatusCode  200};
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

and I want to apply following attributes on the `Get()` method:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(TEntity), 200)] //this causes compilation error.
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Object), 404)]
```

For now, the only work around is to override each method in derived controller and add attributes there:

```
public class DerivedController ：EntityController<MyEntity>
{
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TEntity), (int) HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Object), (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        return base.Get(id);
    }
}
```

Ihis is very inconvenient that I should override every REST methods in every controller, just for use the concrete `TEntity` type in attributes.  :-(

Any better work arounds?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that a generic type parameter is resolved at runtime. But, an attribute parameter must be resolved at compile time. Thus, you can't use a generic type parameter as an argument to an attribute. You can have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9h2ax10.aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-sharp-forbid-generic-attribute-types) for more. For the workaround, I'd try to push something if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Althrough I found no way to use generic type parameter in `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute`, I found another way to make swagger work:

Use `IApplicationModelConvention` to update `ApplicationModel`, which is used by swagger.

```
public class EntityControllerConversion : IApplicationModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
    {
        ActionModel action = ... // finds the controller action 
        Type viewModelType = ... // get the view type by reflection from the controller
        SetResponseUsingHack(action, viewModelType, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    private void SetResponseUsingHack(ActionModel actionModel, Type responseType, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        if (actionModel == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionModel));
        if (responseType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(responseType));

        var writable = (IList<object>)(actionModel.Attributes);
        var attribute = FindResponseAttributeUsingHack(writable, statusCode);
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            attribute.Type = responseType;
        }
    }

    private ProducesResponseTypeAttribute FindResponseAttributeUsingHack(IList<object> attributes, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        if (attributes == null) return null;
        var result = attributes.OfType<ProducesResponseTypeAttribute>()
            .Where(x => x.Type == typeof(ProducesResponseStub))
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StatusCode == (int) statusCode);
        return result;
    }
}

public abstract class EntityController<TEntity> 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProducesResponseStub), 200)]
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
    }
}

public static class ProducesResponseStub
{
}
```

NOTE: Swagger won't work correctly if you just add a new `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute` instance to `ActionModel.Attributes`, may be it's a bug in swagger or in asp.net core. That why I use `ProducesResponseStub` in decorating action methods in `EntityController` and replace them with correct types in `EntityControllerConversion`.

Comment: your answer saved my day. Also, it took me about 20-30 minutes to find out the information on how to register the instance of IApplicationModelConvention in asp.net core startup. As just adding the implementation into web project didn't get the result.

Answer (score 11):

Since `.NET Core 2.1` instead of using `IActionResult`, you can use `ActionResult<TEntity>` as `returntype` (or `Task<ActionResult<TEntity>>`) and then `swagger` will also know the `returntype` for `200` calls!

Answer (score -2):

The DefaultApiDescriptionProvider in package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer has been improved so that it will pick up method return type.

Note that the [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)] attribute is required when other [ProducesResponseType] attributes are specified as shown below:

```
    [HttpGet, Route("")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(ProblemDetailsResponse))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, Type = typeof(ProblemDetailsResponse))]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TResponse>> GetAll(int imoNo)
    {
        var parameters = await _parameterService.GetAllAsync(imoNo);

        return parameters.Select(x => MapToResponse(x));
    }
```

Confirmed to work in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer v2.2.0.

Also work with StatusCodes.Status201Created.