# ActionResult<TValue> in vanilla ASP.NET (non ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle, nswag

I'm trying to integrate Swagger into a somewhat big vanilla ASP.NET MVC app. I was going to use Swashbuckle or NSwag after reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-2.1). The problem is my controllers are inhereted from the generic base class like this:

```
public class BookController : BaseController<Book>
```

And then I have a GET method in a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : ApiController where T : SomeEntityConstraint
{
    ...
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        T queryResult = _repository.Get(id)
        ...
        return Ok(queryResult);
    }
}
```

I was planning to add `[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(T))]` attribute to a method and this is where I got CSharp'd hard. Apparetnly [one can't simply use generic type parameters in an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-sharp-forbid-generic-attribute-types/294259#294259). They must be known at compile time.

I [can see from here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger/samples/2.1/TodoApi.NSwag/Controllers/TodoController.cs#L76) that ASP.NET Core has a neat [`ActionResult<TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class. But I can't find a substitute in a vanilla ASP.NET. I wonder what I can do in situation like this without introducing unwanted coupling and methods overriding in concrete Controller classes implementation or moving the project to a brand new ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure you can implement an own ActionResult class which inherits from IHttpActionResult and just acts as proxy... i think NSwag will pick it up as if it were the ASP.NET Core one...

Disclaimer: I’m one of the devs of NSwag...