# How to apply a generic JsonConverter to a property of a generic class when the property type includes the generic type?

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

I have a problem with Json.NET. I need to use different generic JsonConverters for different properties in one class that is also generic, when the property types include the generic type parameter of the class itself.

Let's have the following generic class where the parameter `TTable` is used by some properties requiring conversion:

```
public class ExpresssionDTO<TTable> : BaseDTO where TTable : class
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(PredicateSerializationConverter<>))]
    public ICollection<Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>> Predicates { get; set; } = new List<Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>>();

    [JsonConverter(converterType: typeof(FilterSerializationConverter<>))]
    public Expression<Func<TTable, object>> Filter { get; set; } = null;
}
```

With converters:

```
public class PredicateSerializationConverter<TTable> : ExpressionSerializer<TTable, bool> where TTable : class
{
    public PredicateSerializationConverter() :base()
    {
    }
}

public class FilterSerializationConverter<TTable> : ExpressionSerializer<TTable, object> where TTable : class
{
    public FilterSerializationConverter() : base()
    {
    }
}

public class ExpressionSerializer<T, U> : JsonConverter where T : class     
{
    ...
}
```

In my contract resolver I have an error:

```
Cannot create an instance of WebFoundationClassesCore.ServiceClasses.Converters.PredicateSerializationConverter`1[TTable] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.
```

This problem also raised for `DefaultContractResolver`.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Put the type of the property into the empty `<>`

Comment: @Charlieface that does not work too - I have compiler time error if I try to pass generic type into the brackets.

Comment: `PredicateSerializationConverter<List<Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>>>` What error does that give?

Comment: @Charlieface Compiler time error

Comment: You can't use generic parameters in attributes, see [Why does C# forbid generic attribute types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294216/3744182).  The actual type is passed in as an argument to [`ReadJson(JsonReader, Type objectType, Object, JsonSerializer)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) and `WriteJson()` so you will need to make your converter nongeneric and do everything by reflection therein.  Or, you could apply the converters using a custom contract resolver.  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc JamesNK gave a solution for generic JsonConverters, but it couldn't be widened to my case. See here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1332

Comment: @dbc Argh forgot that. Typical of MS, let's create this cool feature but disallow it in a few random locations, then spend precious development time *re*-allowing it. See also Enum as a generic constraint, which they disallowed for no reason and only just allowed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to use the generic parameter `TTable` as the generic parameter for your custom JSON converters like so:

```
public class ExpresssionDTO<TTable> : BaseDTO where TTable : class
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(PredicateSerializationConverter<TTable>))] // Here
    public ICollection<Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>> Predicates { get; set; } = new List<Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>>();

    [JsonConverter(converterType: typeof(FilterSerializationConverter<TTable>))] // And here
    public Expression<Func<TTable, object>> Filter { get; set; } = null;
}
```

But you cannot because c# [forbids generic parameters in attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294216/3744182).  It seems you are hoping that, if you specify an open generic type for the converter, and the parent object type is also a generic type with the same number of generic arguments, then Json.NET will automatically construct the converter by plugging in the parent's generic arguments -- here `TTable`.  Unfortunately, this is not implemented.

So, what are your options?

**Firstly**, you could create a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) inheriting from [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) that constructs and applies the appropriate concrete generic converters.  Since you are applying the converters to properties, you will need to override [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperty.htm) and set [`JsonProperty.Converter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_Converter.htm) or [`JsonProperty.ItemConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_ItemConverter.htm) as required.

**Secondly**, you could abandon the generic converter approach and create non-generic converters for serializing filters and predicates.  You can do this because, while using generics when writing converters is convenient and readable, it isn't strictly necessary, as all required type information is passed into the non-generic read and write methods:

- [`JsonConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader, Type objectType, Object, JsonSerializer)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm)

  The `objectType` indicates the required type to deserialize, e.g. `Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>` for `PredicateSerializationConverter`.
- [`JsonConverter.WriteJson(JsonWriter, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm).

  Here the `value` is the actual expression being serialized, so of course its type is known.

You question does not show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your `ExpressionSerializer<T, U>`.  If you can easily rewrite it to be non-generic, then you should consider doing so.  If not, you could adopt the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and wrap your existing generic converters in a decorator that infers the required generic parameters from the `objectType` or `value` like so:

```
public class GenericFuncExpressionArgumentConverterDecorator : JsonConverter
{
    readonly Type openGenericConverterType;
    volatile Tuple<Type, JsonConverter> converterCache;
            
    public GenericFuncExpressionArgumentConverterDecorator(Type openGenericConverterType)
    {
        if (openGenericConverterType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!openGenericConverterType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(JsonConverter)))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not a JsonConvreter", GetType().Name));
        if (!openGenericConverterType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not an open generic type", GetType().Name));
        this.openGenericConverterType = openGenericConverterType;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("{0} is intended to be applied via a JsonConverter or JsonProperty attribute", GetType().Name));

    JsonConverter GetConverter(Type objectType)
    {
        var cache = converterCache;
        if (cache != null && cache.Item1 == objectType)
            return cache.Item2;
        // Despite the documentation, Expression<T> is not actually sealed in .Net 5!
        // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/LambdaExpression.cs#L174
        var expressionType = objectType.BaseTypesAndSelf().Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Expression<>)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (expressionType == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid expression type {0}", objectType));
        var delegateType = objectType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
        if (!delegateType.IsGenericType || delegateType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Func<,>))
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid delegate type {0}", delegateType));
        var argType = delegateType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var converterType = openGenericConverterType.MakeGenericType(new [] { argType });
        var converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType);
        converterCache = Tuple.Create(objectType, converter);
        return converter;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        GetConverter(objectType).ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        GetConverter(value.GetType()).WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

And then apply it to your model as follows, passing the open generic converter types as converter arguments:

```
public class ExpresssionDTO<TTable> : BaseDTO where TTable : class
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(GenericFuncExpressionArgumentConverterDecorator), ItemConverterParameters = new object [] { typeof(PredicateSerializationConverter<>) })]
    public ICollection<Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>> Predicates { get; set; } = new List<Expression<Func<TTable, bool>>>();

    [JsonConverter(typeof(GenericFuncExpressionArgumentConverterDecorator), new object [] { typeof(FilterSerializationConverter<>) })]
    public Expression<Func<TTable, object>> Filter { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PDb4R3).